# Write array to text file with new line using Typescript

Tags: javascript, file, typescript, blob

I have array of plain strings. I want to make save it to text file. Problem is I'm getting it as comma separated values, I want those strings in new line.

Data I have:
[image]

File I'm getting:
[image]
I'm creating file like this

```
let newFile = new Blob([result['list']], {type: "text/plain", endings: 'native'});
```

where result is coming from server. 
How do I make array elements come in new line in text file using File/Blob? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code and data as text, not as images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the array `[1,2,3]` is turned into a string `"1,2,3"`. You can see this by running `String([1,2,3])` in your browser console.

To get around this, try:

```
let newFile = new Blob([result['list'].join('\n')], {type: "text/plain", endings: 'native'});
```